# How to hide a control if the underlying DataContext is null?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, binding, datacontext

I have an object in my view model that has a bunch of properties, some of them will occasionally be null. I don't want to just show some controls if these particular controls are null. How would I go about hiding the control if the bind is null? I was thinking of some sort of converter, but don't know how I'd go about doing it exactly. Any ideas?

edit: sorry, I should mention that this will also be in Silverlight, so I'm not sure if Style triggers would work...?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have a converter like follows,

```
public sealed class NullToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? Visibility.Hidden: Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now, bind the property with the Visibility property as well. Like,

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Squad}" 
         Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource nullToVisibilityConverter}, 
                              Path=Squad}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I'm sure that would work, except the controls aren't even calling the converter Convert method. The control that ISN'T null does, but the others do not.

Comment: This accepted answer is not correct. As Harry said, you have to use TargetNullValue.

Comment: Where do you instantiate *nullToVisibilityConverter*? I see a class with that name but it's capitalized, whereas the parameter in XAML code is lower-cased...

Answer (score 40):

This approach is easier:

```
<CheckBox Visibility="{Binding Path=checkedField, TargetNullValue=Collapsed }">
```

When the bound property `checkedField` is null, the Visibility will be set to Collapsed.

Comment: Is this supposed to re-show the CheckBox when the property is no longer null?

Comment: If datacontext is an object of MyType (for example) and it is not null there's an exception being thrown:
    __Cannot convert 'MyApp.ViewModels.MyType' from type 'MyType' to type 'System.Windows.Visibility'__

It appears that the property used in Path should be somehow convertible into type 'Visibility', which is hardly possible in general case.

Comment: If not `checkedField` but `obj` (with `obj.checkedField`) is null then use point-syntax for `Path` property `<CheckBox Visibility="{Binding Path=., TargetNullValue=Collapsed }">`

Comment: -1 This throws an exception if `checkedField` is not a `Visibility`.

Answer (score 5):

I also needed this for a WindowsPhone WinRT app. I ended up using [@PrinceAshitaka's converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5323969/1000257) with a minor modification in the binding as suggested in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21511608/1000257)

You should use `FallbackValue=Collapsed` to avoid showing the control precisely when the datacontext is null. Not sure why `TargetNullValue=Collapsed` didn't work for me.

```
Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"
```

Answer (score 4):

In Silverlight you can use next approach - add trigger to control:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <core:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeProperty}" Comparison="Equal" Value="{x:Null}">
        <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </core:DataTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `DataContextChanged` event, when the DataContext is null you could set the Visbility to `Collapsed`

read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontextchanged.aspx)

Comment: But in this case you have to use code behind - it would be MVVM incompatible.

Comment: MVVM is just a guideline. It's appropriate to use code-behind when designing logic that is specific to that control.

Answer (score 0):

Needed this, but I couldn't get it to work within a DataTemplate inside a DataGridTemplateColumn, so here is my example of how I got it to work.

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.AvailableHierarchies, 
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                            AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}} }"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedHierarchy, 
                                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                             AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"
                                      >
            <ComboBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ComboBox.ItemsSource" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.Style>
        </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining [bugfixr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323817/how-to-hide-a-control-if-the-underlying-datacontext-is-null/9702146#9702146) with [Phil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893825/mvvm-hiding-a-control-when-bound-property-is-not-present/9893968#9893968), I came up with (in WPF):

```xml
<Button
    Name="Button1"
    Click="Button1_Click"
    Content="{Binding Path=ActiveSubJob.ButtonText[0]}"
    Visibility="{Binding Path=ActiveSubJob.ButtonText[0],
                         Converter={StaticResource AlwaysVisibleConverter},
                         FallbackValue=Collapsed,
                         TargetNullValue=Collapsed}"
    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsButton1Enabled}"
    />
```

Had to adjust the `Convert` method of Phil's `AlwaysVisibleConverter` a bit to make `TargetNullValue` work correctly:

```cs
public object? Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return Visibility.Visible;
}
```