# Hiding a GroupBox control when its DataContext is null

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `GroupBox` on which I set the `DataContext` in the code behind at different stages. I am trying to have this `GroupBox` hidden when its `DataContext` is null. I looked at this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323817/how-to-hide-a-control-if-the-underlying-datacontext-is-null) but it may not apply in this case.
I have a member boolean property `SelectedViewVisible` which I try to call on the `Window` in the code behind, but it does not seem to get called with `DataContext` set to null.

I am using the following converter in `<Window.Resources>` and have it working successfully on other controls, so the issue should not have to do with it:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
```

The following is the declaration of my `GroupBox`:

```
<GroupBox ... 
     Visibility="{Binding Path=SelectedViewVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
```

Without `Path` does not work either:

```
Visibility="{Binding SelectedViewVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"
```

Maybe I just am confused between static and member binding properties ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using `DataTrigger` and checking for `{x:Null}` value for DataContext:

```
    <GroupBox Header="Test">
        <GroupBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="GroupBox">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </GroupBox.Style>
    </GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `FallbackValue`, it is the value that is used if the binding does not yield a value:

```
 <GroupBox ... 
 Visibility="{Binding Path=SelectedViewVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}">
```