# NullToVisibilityConverter make visible if not null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Want to hide and show property grid for **SelectedItem** in listview

```
<UserControl xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
      <ListView>
         <!--here is list view-->
      </ListView>
      <xctk:PropertyGrid SelectedObject="{Binding Active}" Visibility="{Binding Active, Converter=NullToVisibilityConverter}" >  
   </xctk:PropertyGrid>
</UserControl>
```

So I need converter and use it in visibility property converter. Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a control if the underlying DataContext is null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323817/how-to-hide-a-control-if-the-underlying-datacontext-is-null)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
public class NullVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then reference the NullVisibilityConverter in your XAML Resources.

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
  <simpleXamlContent:NullVisibilityConverter x:Key="NullToVisibilityConverter"/>
</StackPanel.Resources>
```

Comment: how to use it in my xaml?

Comment: ```<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding MyObject, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}">```

Answer (score 8):

To use the converter we can create one in the resources, and refer to it as a static resource in the binding statement.

```
<UserControl xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit">
    <UserControl.Resources>
      <yournamespace:NullVisibilityConverter x:Key="NullToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <ListView>
    <!--here is list view-->
    </ListView>

    <xctk:PropertyGrid SelectedObject="{Binding Active}" Visibility="{Binding Active, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}" >  
    </xctk:PropertyGrid>
</UserControl>
```

and Converter class itself

```
public class NullVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing how to implement the NullToVisibilityConverter.  I have a DataGrid that gets a refresh button, but only in certain instances.  Setting the Button's Image source to null hid the image but left the button which was visible when the mouse was over.  I used this converter on the Button's Visibility property and it worked perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

There is little more useful version allows to set default invisibility value:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    string defaultInvisibility = parameter as string;
    Visibility invisibility = (defaultInvisibility != null) ?
        (Visibility)Enum.Parse(typeof(Visibility), defaultInvisibility)
        : Visibility.Collapsed;
    return value == null ? invisibility : Visibility.Visible;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
}
```

Where ever in resources add:

```
<converters:NullReferenceToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NullToVis" />
```

And use it like there:

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding MyObject, Converter={StaticResource NullToVis}}">
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding MyObject, Converter={StaticResource NullToVis}, ConverterParameter=Hidden}">
```