# Hide item if binded value is null?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a `ListBox` like this:

```
<ListBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
         ItemsSource="{Binding EventInfo}">
```

inside it I've a `DataTemplate` with a list of TextBlock:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Text="Event:" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
         </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

what I need to do is hide the textblock when for example, the binded value is `null`. I've associate this stuff:

```
Event: foo
```

but in some case the `Name` is null, I need to hide both `TextBlock` `Event` and the binded, is possible do this?

**UPDATE:**

I'm trying to do this pure in xaml as:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
     <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
              <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
              <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
          </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The problem's that the application fall in interruption mode and as xaml error I get:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Name' property not found on 'object' ''Style' (HashCode=7)'.

this error is repeated for each textblock that I've what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind the visibility to a property

```
Visibility="{Binding IsVisibleName, Converter={StaticResource myBoolToVisibilityConverter}}
```

through a static bool converter

```
<local:BooleanToVisibiltyConverter x:Key="myBoolToVisibilityConverter" />
```

for all the elements that must/can be hidden.

Then converter transforms true into visible

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    bool isVisible = (bool)value;
    return (isVisible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed);
}
```

Then you'll set them when the conditions are met, like for example (this is a general idea, I don't know about your specific details) in the Name setter (and you have to configure all the other triggers as well)

```
public string Name 
{
   get { return name;}
   set 
   { 
      name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name");
      IsVisibleName = name != null; IsVisibleEvent = event != null && name != null;
   }
}
```

In pure XAML there are data triggers

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeValue}" Value=" x:Null ">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: isn't possible do this only in pure xaml?

Comment: Yes, you can define the data triggers in pure xaml, but I personally find the setter method clearer and more powerful... I'll edit my answer to insert an example of xaml trigger as well

Comment: could you please see my update? I'm trying to do this pure in xaml but I suppose that's something wrong in my code.

Comment: I'd suggest a data trigger. I've drafted a starting point as an example...

Comment: hey, is possible also hide the row where the textblock have as container?

Comment: You have the same options already presented here, in shorts: filtering out the row from the items at VM level in the first place; using the Visibility binding that I've initially suggested as more powerful on whatever xaml element it might concern or finally in pure xaml issuing another data trigger for a style of that target type. Difficult to get deeper insight by comments. Open a follow-up question if you really deem there's something more specific to your project.

Comment: just opened a new complete question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307839/remove-row-if-textblock-binded-value-is-null maybe you could take a look, thanks

Answer (score 2):

While you could use a [NullToVisibilityConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21939778/628821) here, you will probably find that there is a suspicious gap in your ListBox where the (collapsed) TextBlock's should be due to padding around the ListBoxItemContainer. Worse still, this "gap" could still be selected by the user.

Although these issues could also be resolved using an approach similar to the NullToVisbilityConverter I would very much encourage you to filter out these values from the EventInfo in your ViewModel where logic about **what** should be presented to the user (but excluding **how** it should be presented) should be located.

Comment: Man, I wish I read this before jumping into my answer. Yours is the correct approach - just facade the base list into an `ObservableCollection` and filter out the nulls from there, and bind the listbox to the `ObservableCollection` and do an notifypropchange at relevant points of code (e.g. the item becomes null in the base list)