# Remove row if textblock binded value is null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I just ask a similar question but I noticed for my bad, I need to hide the entire row and not only the textblock. Let me explain what happen. So I've a ListBox with this structure:

```
<ListBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
     ItemsSource="{Binding EventInfo}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Text="Event:" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
          <TextBlock Text="Foo:" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo}" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
         </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

so what I need to do is hide all the rows that contains the `textblock`/s with a null or empty value, actually I managed this in pure xaml like this:

```
<ListBox.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

but this is not a good solution. Infact, how you can see I've each `textblock` organized by row and column, so I need to hide the row that contain the textblock with the null value.

With my solution, I only hide the textblock with null value, that is useless 'cause the value is already empty or null.

There is a chance to manage it through xaml? I've no idea how can I do this in xaml, 'cause if I hide a row in the middle for example, I'll get a blank space with the row that contains textblocks with not null value. I don't know if the situation is clear.

If something is unclear, ask and I'll try to explain better. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the Grid Row Height accordingly

Replace

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

with

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition.Style>
            <Style TargetType="RowDefinition">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="">
                        <Setter  Property="Height" Value="0" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter  Property="Height" Value="0" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </RowDefinition.Style>
    </RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition.Style>
            <Style TargetType="RowDefinition">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Foo}" Value="">
                        <Setter  Property="Height" Value="0" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Foo}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter  Property="Height" Value="0" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </RowDefinition.Style>
    </RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Funk I'm trying to implement your code, but I don't understand a thing: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>` should be placed after the `RowDefinitions`?

Comment: Okay I understood the logic now, very interesting, I didn't know this practice. Really thanks for this solution :) have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Converters?
You can write a converter for string to visibility, like this:

```
public class EmptyNotVisibleConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (_converter == null)
            _converter = new EmptyNotVisibleConverter();
        return _converter;
    }

    private static EmptyNotVisibleConverter _converter = null;
}
```

And use it on your Grid like this:

```
<Grid Visibility={Binding Name, Converter={local:EmptyNotVisibleConverter}}>
```