# Filtering null values in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am making a UWP app that makes call to a web service and displays the data. I am deserializing the response JSON into C# class and storing it in a ObservableCollection. There's a ListView on my XAML page that binds to this XAML.

But the problem is that the response JSON can sometimes contain null for certain keys. In such cases I just want the XAML code to omit such TextBlocks that Bind to null values. How do I achieve that?

Here's a snippet of my XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="Author"/>
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Author}"/>

<TextBlock Text="Education Level"/>
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind EducationLevel}"/>
```

Some of these {x:Bind XXX} values can be null and I want to not show such fields.

Comment: You need to filter the source collection. If you show me how you populate the ListView, both the XAML and the viewmodel property, I can help you with that.

Comment: @EdPlunkett added.

Comment: Provide the information I requested

Comment: Good luck with your problem.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a converter class for this.

```
public class NullStringToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var s = (string) value;
        return (s!=null) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then instanciate the converter in your Page resources:

```
<local:NullStringToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NullStringToVisibilityConverter" />
```

And update your xaml with a binding on Visibility attributes:

```
<TextBlock Text="Author" Visibility="{x:Bind Author, Converter={StaticResource NullStringToVisibilityConverter}}" />
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Author}" Visibility="{x:Bind Author, Converter={StaticResource NullStringToVisibilityConverter}}" />

<TextBlock Text="Education Level" Visibility="{x:Bind EducationLevel, Converter={StaticResource NullStringToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind EducationLevel}" Visibility="{x:Bind EducationLevel, Converter={StaticResource NullStringToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to implement a `NullToVisibilityConverter` so that you can hide `TextBlock`'s that would be bound to null.  Follow the example in this related question:

[NullToVisibilityConverter make visible if not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939667/nulltovisibilityconverter-make-visible-if-not-null)